# Android achartengine axis labels

Tags: java, android, achartengine

Is there a way to make my axis labels images?

It would make more visual sense in my app if I could.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: What if i can put a layout behind it and position the images beside the graph and tunr off th eY axis - does this sound plausable?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead and try it :)

Comment: @Fearghal is your solution worked or not ? Because I want to do the same I want to add Images on XAxis.